# Php variable in a html table

Tags: php, html, html-table

I'm trying to display an html table in which I'd like to show some php variables.

My code is the following:

```
<?php
$title = the_title();
?>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $title?></td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

In the output I can see the word "Name" as expected but it doesn't print the $title variable (there is a empty space instead).
I've already read some of the questions on the site but they doesn't help me because they suggest to write the same code that I wrote.

Comment: So what is `the_title()` do?

Comment: I think the problem is that I used that function in a bad way. All the information are here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title/

Comment: If you're using Wordpress, then you should either do `$title = get_the_title();`. Another alternative would be to just do `<?php the_title() ?>` in the table. The function `the_title()`, _outputs_ the title while `get_the_title()` _returns_ the title so you can store it in a variable.

Comment: @Maria - For next time, do the research (like reading the docs, google etc) _before_ posting here. This should be the place you come to after you've already done the [appropriate amount of research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) but are still stuck.

Comment: You are right, thank you! Using get_the_title() is working!

Comment: Add a semicolon after `echo $title` -> `<?php echo $title; ?>`